# How to simulate the behavior of a remote desktop without showing the screen

Tags: windows, sockets, remote-desktop, rdp, udpclient

I should make a program that **simulates the behavior of a remote desktop** but **without showing the screen** of the server to the client.

I can use any programming language, but the client must be on Android mobile device and the server's operating system must be Windows.

I do not know how to Start. I was thinking about two possibilities:

1- **Use a socket**. But the difficulty was to give commands outside of the programming environment.

2- Use a **rdp already done** but turn off the display screen (setting is not present in the rdp I know). Who can help me?
Thank you

Comment: Let's take a step back - unless this is a homework assignment, what is the bigger picture / thing that you are trying to do?

Comment: @cdavid I don't understand what you mean by 'the bigger picture/ thing   that you are trying to do". Anyway, I'll explain in a better way. I should make a program in which a device connects to a server and performs  commands to take action outside of the programming environment.  For example typing a letter on the keyboard of the device, the program must display the same letter on the notepad of the server.  But the client will be without a graphic user interface, just connect to the server and send commands.

Comment: As far as I know, what you are trying to do is not possible. This is why I was actually looking for more details on what you are trying to achieve - maybe there is another option. Is it just commands that the server must execute (case in which a "remote commandline" might work)? Better yet - where does your input go (where do the keys that you type on the client go)? Do you also need output?